# Media streaming on Windows 7 not working with my Dual Radio 700

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

I have enabled media streaming in Windows Media Player in Win 7. I have a radio from Sagem that works with WMP which worked with Vista, but now it does not with Win 7.

How can I test whether Win 7 media streaming is working? I have another laptop running XP on the network. Can I test it from there?

Comment: is there software you had to install for the radio on Vista?

Comment: No, it just listens for a media server

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your problem is mostly fixed by doing the following:

1) open services.msc and Disable "Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service"

2) Go to the following hidden folder:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player (where  is the the account you're logged in as)

3) Delete the Media Player folder (this will be recreated)

4) Open Windows Media Player 12 and head to Stream -> Turn on Media Streaming

As far as testing I would upgrade the Windows XP device to Windows 7 and [setup media server](https://www.howtogeek.com/215400/how-to-turn-your-computer-into-a-dlna-media-server/)

For more details visit: [MSFT media player streaming](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/cant-turn-on-media-streaming-on-windows-7-media/56a58234-89d2-48da-a7b2-a357dfa776d3)